# Clear the text fields and highlight color in angular js at the time of backside navigation?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```js
.controller('SinginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicHistory, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $rootScope, BuynowFactory, $timeout) {

      alert("sign");
      $scope.myGoBack = function() {
        if ($ionicHistory.backView() == null) {

          $location.path("/app/home");
        };
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
      };
      $scope.inputType = 'password';
      $scope.errorMessage = '';

      $scope.signIn = function(authorizationForm) {
          $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Loading',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
          });

          var email = authorizationForm.emailId;

          var password = authorizationForm.password;
          var data = {
            emailId: email,
            passwordId: password
          };

          $http.post('http://www.otcdeal.com/OTCDealWS/OTCDealLoginService.php', data).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $timeout(function() {
              $ionicLoading.hide();
            }, 0);
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="RegistrationForm" ng-submit="registrationDetails(RegistrationDetails)" novalidate>
  <h3> REGISTER WITH US </h3>
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label min-margin" ng-class="{'has-errors':RegistrationForm.UserName.$invalid && RegistrationForm.UserName.$touched}">
      <span class="input-label">Your Name</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" ng-model="RegistrationDetails.UserName" name="UserName" required>
    </label>
    <p class="message-error" ng-show="RegistrationForm.UserName.$error.required && RegistrationForm.UserName.$touched">user name is required</p>

    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-class="{'has-errors':RegistrationForm.LastName.$invalid && RegistrationForm.LastName.$touched}">
      <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="RegistrationDetails.LastName" name="LastName" required>
    </label>
    <p class="message-error" ng-show="RegistrationForm.LastName.$error.required && RegistrationForm.LastName.$touched">LastName is required</p>

    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-class="{'has-errors':RegistrationForm.EmailId.$invalid && RegistrationForm.EmailId.$touched}">
      <span class="input-label">Email</span>
      <input type="email" placeholder="username@domain.com" ng-model="RegistrationDetails.EmailId" name="EmailId" required>
    </label>
    <p class="message-error" ng-show="RegistrationForm.EmailId.$error.required && RegistrationForm.EmailId.$touched">user name is required</p>
    <p class="message-error" ng-show="RegistrationForm.EmailId.$error.email  && RegistrationForm.EmailId.$touched">please enter valid email address</p>

    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-class="{'has-errors': RegistrationForm.Password.$invalid && RegistrationForm.Password.$touched}">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="{{inputType}}" placeholder="******" ng-minlength="6" ng-model="RegistrationDetails.Password" name="Password" required>
    </label>
    <p class="message-error" ng-show="RegistrationForm.Password.$error.required && RegistrationForm.Password.$touched">password is required</p>
    <p class="message-error" ng-show="RegistrationForm.Password.$error.minlength && RegistrationForm.Password.$touched">Enter password as minimum 6 or more</p>
    <ion-checkbox ng-click="hideShowPassword()" ng-model="filter.blue">Show Password</ion-checkbox>
    <p class="message-error">{{Useravailable}}</p>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-disabled="RegistrationForm.$invalid">SIGNUP</button>
</form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jhr2.png)In My app first three views

1. Language view (English,arabic buttons in page)
2. Sign-view (sign form and have a button create an account(Register) in a page)
3. Register view(Register form)

sign form controller code:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label"  ng-class="{'has-errors':LoginForm.MobileNumber.$invalid && LoginForm.MobileNumber.$touched}"> 
<span class="input-label">Mobile Number</span>
```

how to clear the has error class and fileds as normal when return from register view to sign view

Comment: Can u create a fiddle ?

Comment: sorry its going to be big process form me

Comment: You don't have to setup your whole app in the fiddle, just a minimal example. That can't be a so big process, and then it won't be a big process for anybody to help or answer to you

Comment: did you try cache-view="false" on the login page?

Comment: no .how to add that one

Comment: yeah thank u so much ..that one is solved my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cache-view="false"

This above line is solved my answer